# Evaluate the definite integral: $\int_0^\infty e^{-hx^2}\;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

where $h>0$.
Could someone explain to me how to solve it?
I searched the internet and I found the result is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{h}}$ but I couldn't undersand Gauss error function - that is involved in solving.

Comment: it was a minus, sorry

Comment: Set $x=y/\sqrt h$

Comment: Is your question about how to compute the Gaussian integral itself? You can look this up on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Computation and many other places including MSE

Comment: that constant h it gives me some troubles